# Java. Io. IOException:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: jsf, weblogic12c

I am trying to download csv file from remote server to local server but i am getting `Java.Io.IOException` error. 
My war file deployed on `weblogic 12.2.1.3` server with ssl enabled and using jsf2. 2 functionality.

Comment: look at your question, nobody can see the image ...

Comment: I guess your web browser closed a connection. Please read [ask] and consider [mcve]

Comment: Not able to upload image..